# Range Not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use [Range(1f,3f)] in front of my int in unity so that I can get a slider in my inspector. But it gives an error that says "The namespace name Range could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or assembly reference". With every example I find no one does it different then me, could it be because I use an older version of Unity? And how can I make it possible in this version or is that impossible?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class AssignMaterial : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool assignMaterial;
    [Range(1, 3)] public int matId;

    void Update()
    {
        if(assignMaterial)
        {
            switch(matId)
            {
                case 1:
                this.renderer.material = Resources.Load("NodeMaterial" + matId.ToString()) as Material;
                break;
                case 2:
                this.renderer.material = Resources.Load("NodeMaterial" + matId.ToString()) as Material;
                break;
                case 3:
                this.renderer.material = Resources.Load("NodeMaterial" + matId.ToString()) as Material;
                break;
            }
        DestroyImmediate(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to limit a `int` with `floats` ? And do you have `using UnityEngine;` In the top of the script?

Comment: O sorry my mistake no I am using ints wasnt thinking when I typed it here, but yes I have using UnityEngine; in the top

Comment: old version of unity? Which version exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be the case that this is a not supported in the version you are using. 
The lowest version I could confirm myself with the range attribute implemented was unity 4.2

Alternatively to the range attribute you could make a editor script instead. With a line saying something like:

```
AssignMaterial.matID = (int)EditorGUILayout.Slider(AssignMaterial.matID, 0, 3);
```

*small side note*

You might want to get some try/catches in there. As it is right now, if there is no renderer attached to the object. You will freeze up unity for a bit, while it is better to catch this error and dispose of the process if this is not assigned.